# split string which is the content of word document using strtok on <h1> and <p> tag using php

Tags: php, html, string, strtok

I am using WAMP I have to read the content of word document from the upload folder on server .The word document contains headings containing heading style (heading 1) and paragraphs.the function given below converts the document into readable text and I am storing the result of this function in a variable let say `$result`;

```
private function read_docx(){

    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    $zip = zip_open($this->filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
```

I am putting `<h1></h1>` tags around headings and `<p></p>` tags around paragraphs in word document.
I want to split $wordread string using strtok function as given below

```
$tok = strtok( $wordread, "<p>");

while ($tok !== false) {
    echo "Word=$tok<br />";
    $tok = strtok("<p>");
}
```

For example I have a word file which contains `<p>this is paragraph</p>`. I want to extract "this is paragraph" help me to get all paragraphs and headings in two different arrays.

Comment: Why don't you try actually parsing the XML rather than simply treating it as  string containing characters you don't want?

Comment: thanks Mark but its the requirement to read the string without going into XML

Comment: What's forcing you to use the wrong tool for the job instead of the correct tool?

Comment: Any body would like to answer that can lead me towards solution